# jqm listview onclick still following href

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile listview with a delete button next to an  link in each list item. When I click the delete button, the onclick event fires, the delete function runs but then the href is also followed, even though the button isn't nested within the href. I have added return false to the button to see if that would help but it doesn't! HELP!

Here's the code I'm using to dynamically populate my list....

```
$('#roomsList').append('<li><img src="img/delete-2x.png" class="delete" onClick="deleteRoom(\'' + currentRow.roomtype + '\',\'' + propertyID + '\'); return false;" /><a href="inventory.html?roomtype='+currentRow.roomtype+'&id='+propertyID+'" id="'+currentRow.roomtype+'">' + currentRow.roomtype + '</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problems. Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WEmNG/. I have created it two days ago for someone else but it is similar to your question. Instead of delete button I am showing custom checkbox on a listview. If you click a listview it will forward you to another page but if you click on the custom checkbox it will only activate event on chechbox.

Use my example to create a working delete button on a listview.

This is an example of event I am using on my custom checkbox:

```
$('.checkBoxLeft').bind('click', function(e) {
   if($(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
       $(this).removeClass('checked').addClass('not-checked');
       $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked' , false);
   } else {
       $(this).removeClass('not-checked').addClass('checked');             
       $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked' , true);
   }
});
```

Comment: I can see this is working for you but as soon as I replace the checkbox with an image, it follows the href. I am confused!

Comment: Wrap image inside a DIV. Set DIv with absolute position, float it to correct location. I think this will prevent your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Append both  the a and the li to the parent [ put them on the same level]. In this way they it should work easily.

Comment: Do you mean put the image tag and the a tag on the same level? that's what's already happening. I tried taking the image out of the li tag as below but then it just disappears. 

    <ul><img src="stuff"/><li><a href="#">Link</a></li></ul>